# How do I fix the bug below and get the result I want

Tags: ocaml

I have code below, but I don't get the correct result I want

```ocaml
type expr
= Val of value 
| App of expr * expr
| MultiApp of expr * expr list
and value 
= Int of int 
| Bool of bool

let rec t(e:expr) : expr = match e with
| Val _ -> e
| App(f,a) -> App(t f, t a)

| MultiApp(f,[]) -> raise (Failure "no")
| MultiApp(f,lst) -> match lst with
                        |[]-> raise (Failure "no")
                        |x::xs -> let rest = MultiApp(f,xs) in 

                             App(f,x) 

let e1 = Val(Int 1)
let e2 = Val(Int 3)
let e3 = Val(Bool true)
let e4 = Val(Bool false)
```

For example,

```
MultiApp(fe,[e1;e2;e3])
```

after apply fun `t` it would get something like

```
App(App(App(t fe, t e1), t e2) t e3)
```

Comment: Why not have the result be `MultiApp(t fe,[t e1;t e2;t e3])` instead of expanding it here?

Comment: The first branch of the inner match for `MultiApp(f,lst)` is unreachable - this case is covered by `MultiApp(f,[])` branch in the outer match. The second obvious problem is that `let rest` binding in the last inner matching branch in `t` is not used at all. It all looks broken (but t be honest it's hard to say for sure because I just don't understand how is this code intended to work :))

Comment: you can just ignore MultiApp(f,[]), how can I fix that to get the correct result

Comment: In addition to the other useful comments above, I note that you almost certainly want to call `t` recursively somewhere in your code for handlng `MultiApp`.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be recusive, but how can I do that?

Comment: Could you please provide a fully executable example with the current result and the desired one? Your current examples are kind of useless (at least because `fe` is not defined)...